# What is the difference between vapour and steam?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, water, definition, phase-transition

What is the difference between [vapour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor) and [steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam)? These two terms seemingly are similar but have different meanings. trying to define these two gets us a similar definition which is not actually true
I tried to think over it but could not.

Answer (score 10):

Depends on which meaning of steam you use; and what you're talking about with vapour.

In general, a vapour refers to the gas phase of a substance below critical temperature.  This means that if pressure changes, the gas can become a liquid without a required temperature change.  This can apply to any substance.

Steam in general refers to the gas phase of water.  Steam can be the same as water vapour in some contexts.  In more casual usage, steam can refer to the mixture of vapour and aerosol liquid water droplets suspended in the vapour.  The "steam" you see rising off boiling water for example, is the second type.  What you see is actually condensed liquid water; as water vapour itself is not visible to the naked eye.

Answer (score 2):

Steam is always a vapour.  The viceversa is not true. Steam is the vapour obtained by heating a substance to its boiling point and as such is "hot", or better at boiling T. Vapour is the gas phases in equilibrium with a substance, or the part of it which escapes in an open system.

Comment: I would really like to know why downvoting. This is correct and that's kindergarten behavior

Comment: Even more so when a basically the same answer is up voted (nothing against the latter, of course.  I could up vote it too).

Comment: I am not a native English speaker but would think that "steam" always refers to H$_2$O.

Comment: Well in most cases we deal with water, that's correct.  But if I will have to distill wine and made a cognac that ethanol vapour is a steam. I do not think of English here, not much.  In my language both vapour and steam are called the same,  for instance.  The only point is what vapour pressure equal to. When it equals atm P then the stuff boils. In English you can that steam. Without droplets, although as the other A said colloquially people think of steam as something wet.

Comment: Probably the original poster's native language does not make the distinction either. So this is to a large extent a question about usage in English. But in that language, I do not think that one can say that "ethanol vapour is (a) steam".

Comment: Sure he/she can if is a chemist/physicist or engineer. Still it is even not relevant to the correctness of my answer.

Comment: And at deep perusal the accepted answer is even not correct.  It does focus on the difference between gas and vapour (of which steam is a special case) rather than that between steam and vapour as in the Question.  The vapour of water atop a liquid water surface is not steam.  Steam is addressed there from casual perspective with no physical insight.

Comment: I just happened to stumble back on this question a long time later.  I believe this may be an issue of English not being your native language.  In English, [steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam) is made of water always.  That is it's definition.  [Vapour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor) is a gas that is below it's critical temperature.  Steam is a special case because it refers to water, and because it's common English usage has led to people referring to suspended condensate as "steam" as well (which is why I included that in my answer).

Comment: I agree that sometimes the down votes on this site are so mysterious...

Comment: @yaobin after long time this gave me the opportunity to upvote the other answer, too.

Comment: @user137289 right it can be. But it is empty of chemical physical significance.

Comment: I think the downvotes are a definition conflict, related to the phrase "Steam is always a vapour." Some people define "vapour" as "gas" whereas others include "small liquid or solid particles suspended in air" as an acceptable definition of the word. Likewise, some people consider "steam" to refer to gaseous water while others call "steam" the visible liquid droplets floating above heated water.